# How do I plot 2 points in a graph in a GUI?

Tags: java, graphing

I am trying to make a GUI that will plot 2 points in a line graph and draw a line segment from those two points.

I cannot find any examples in any of my Java textbooks, and almost every example that I try to search for is too complex to understand in the short amount of time that I have.

Is there anyway to explain graphing easily to a beginner in Java?

Comment: `almost every example that I try to search for is too complex to understand in the short amount of time that I have` - it takes time to learn to program. We are not here to write the code for you, only point you in the right direction. So you can start with `Graphics.drawLine(...)`. Or maybe you want `Graphics.drawPolyline()`

Comment: You could start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and/or [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Comment: Hey, if you're new to programming, I'll share a website with you that really helped me years ago (no affiliation). http://zetcode.com/ It's got a boatload of tutes for Java2D work, both from a non-games and games-oriented aspect, along with tutes for lots of other languages too. Hope that helps you on your path to Java programming glory!

Answer (score 1):

Use a Canvas as your drawing surface.

Use the drawLine() function to draw a line between X1,Y1 and X2,Y2.

There are lots of samples out there for this, such as:
http://mainline.brynmawr.edu/Courses/cs110/fall2003/Applets/CanvasExample/CanvasExample.html

or this:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawcanvaswithcolorandtext.htm

Laurence

Comment: You're first example is out of date - IMHO, better to use Swing where possible

Comment: True...just trying to keep it very simple for the OP

Comment: Always happy for simple :) but you just mixed to different frameworks :P

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, the easiest way to draw lines in a GUI is to use a paint(Graphics g) method. Within that, use g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2); to draw the line.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class JGraph extends JPanel 
{
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
  }
}
```

*On a side note, the coordinate system for this method starts at the top left of the GUI object of choice in the prior code.

Answer (score 0):

How do you search??

[How to draw lines in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801734/how-to-draw-lines-in-java)

[Short example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/GraphicsdrawLineintx1inty1intx2inty2.htm)

And search the API

[Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)

[Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

Comment: It's from java2s.com. :D Blame them.

Comment: I'd love to, but now you've just referenced as a viable good source. Not point blaming the gun manufacture ;)

Answer (score 0):

to draw ultimate lines I have figured out the following code:

```
public void drawUltimate(Graphics g, int x, int y, int x2, int y2){
    int ex=0,ey=0,ex2=0,ey2=0, mx, my;
    mx = x2-x;my = y2-y;
    //drawLine(jPanel1.getGraphics(), x, y, x2, y2);
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
        ex += mx;
        ey += my;

        drawLine(jPanel1.getGraphics(), ex2+1, ey2-2, ex, ey);
        ex2 =ex; ey2 =ey;
    }
}
```