# Visualize complex numbers in Java

Tags: java, plot, complex-numbers

I've been looking for a way to plot complex numbers on the unit circle in Java like this
[image]

But I haven't found any. I'd like to ask if you have some idea about library which could be used, or any other way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at [this](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~squire/download/PoleZeroPlot.java). This is a part of [this project](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~squire/cs455_l18a.html).

This class generates following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to google first:

- [How do I plot 2 points in a graph in a GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390572/how-do-i-plot-2-points-in-a-graph-in-a-gui)
- [How to create Java GUI program for complex mathematical equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065393/how-to-create-java-gui-program-for-complex-mathematical-equations)

or read the java tutorial:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/